# How to do a random border radius scss

Tags: css, function, random, sass, styles

I want to add the unit after a `random($limit: 100)` i want in the css : `border-radius: <the random number>%`

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply the result from `random()` by 1% (or any other unit you may want) to append the unit. The outer parenthesis is a sass feature, so those type of calculations only work with alike-units or unitless + alike-units.

```
  border-radius: (random($limit: 50) * 1%);
```